# How do I find the mean_squared_error of axis zero of a dask array of any dimension (1D, 2D, 3D, 4D..etc)

Tags: arrays, dask

I have been asked to: Given a dask array, compute the difference along axis 0 using mean squared error (note: you will not be able to use your earlier implementation). This can be done without loops -- think outside of the box! This also needs to work for 1D, 2D, 3D, 4D, etc. Don't call .compute()

This is my code so far with test code at the bottom:

'''def MSE_axis0(anArray):

```
    axis_mean = da.mean(anArray, axis=0)

    squared_diff = (anArray - axis_mean) **2

    mse_axis_zero = da.mean(squared_diff, axis=0)

return mse_axis_zero
```

twoD = da.arange(4).reshape((2,2));print(all(isclose(a, b) for a, b in zip(MSE_axis0(twoD), [4.])))
'''

Output: True

My code is not working and I think it is because I don't fully understand how axes work in dask arrays.